# random fade list on refresh

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<ul id="content">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay('1')
     .fadeIn('3000')
     .delay('5000')
     .fadeOut(
               function(){
                   if(elem.next().length > 0)
                   {InOut( elem.next() );}
                   else
                   {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));}

                 }
             );
}

$(function(){
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

This is the work of gaby and below is his fiddle

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/1/

just wanted on how to random the list and on refresh also, so meaning everything is in random order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to randomize the list. The benefit of this is the list will fade in the same order each time and every item will cycle at least once, due to the fade function not being randomized, but the list itself.

```
$(function(){
    // randomize the list
    var list = $("#content"),
        items = $("#content > li"),
        len = items.length;

    while(len--){
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        list.append(items[ran]);
    }

    // hide it and do the fades.
    $('#content li').hide();
    InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Cjm/1182/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/S5Cjm/1180/

```
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay()
     .fadeIn()
     .delay()
     .fadeOut( 
               function(){                    
                   InOut($(jQuery("li").get().sort(function(){ 
                      return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
                    }).slice(0,1)))                         
                 }
             );
}

$(function(){
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

​

Comment: Hi there Bouillou, thanks for that but there are repetitions, can it be without repetitions and when all 6 lists are displayed then repeat those 6 again... sorry im a bit new here

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan not trying to hijack, but thats what my answer does.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to thumb up useful answers and close subject by clicking on the green tick

Answer (score 0):

```
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay()
     .fadeIn()
     .delay()
     .fadeOut( 
               function(){ 
                   if(elem.siblings().length > 0)
                   {InOut( $(elem.siblings('*')[Math.floor(Math.random() * elem.siblings().length)]));}
                   else
                   {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));}

                 }
             );
}

$(function(){
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

Using Math.random() can solve your problem. See the above code for an example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S5Cjm/1179/

JS

```
function InOut( elem )
{
    var ran = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
 elem.delay().fadeIn().delay().fadeOut(function(){ 
     InOut(elem.parent().find('li:nth-child('+ran+')'));
 });
}

$(function(){
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same problems as the other suggested answers, elements wont fully cycle, and you could have the same one repeat a few times in a row. It also makes the assumption there will always only be 6 list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    $('p').show();
    var lis = $('li').hide();

    $('a').click(function() {
        var i = 0;
        (function displayImages() {
            lis.eq(i++).fadeIn(200, displayImages);
        })();
    });

})();
```